# APEX Dropzone Plugin: Drag and Drop from Lotus Notes doesn't work

Tags: drag-and-drop, lotus-notes, dropzone

I installed the Dropzone 2 Plugin in my APEX application. It works fine, when loading files from Windows Explorer via Drag and Drop, but if I try to drag an attachment from Lotus Notes it doesn't work.

My code is very easy. It is just a Dropzone 2 region in the Content body of a page. I tried both Upload mechanism methods (normal or chunked). When I use chunked nothing happens, using normal leads to a database error. It seems that the file is empty and only the picture of the attachment in Lotus Notes is dropped.

The console shows:
code: "AJAX Callback (pData) ParseError"
message: "uploadDzFiles Response ParseError"
status: "error"
The apex_collection is empty.

I tried the same in the demo application from Daniel Hochleitner and it is the same result. Is this a bug in the plugin or a problem from Lotus Notes?

Does someone knows a workaround? Exists another tool for that issue?

Comment: 1) Show your code.  
2) Explain what you have done, and what APEX is in this case. 
3) Be more specific on "doesn't work". What are you trying to do (include the steps taken, so the problem can be reproduced). What is happening? What error message are you getting?

Comment: What are you trying to drop into the plugin? An file that is an attachment to a Lotus Notes document? I would not expect that to work in a plugin that accepts files dropped from Windows Explorer. I would not consider it a bug in the plugin or a problem in Lotus Notes, either. Attachments in Notes have icons that look like files, but they are not stored as files.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried. Take an attachment of a Lotus Notes document and drop it in the Dropzone element of my APEX application. If I do it in two steps (drop the attachment in the windows explorer and then drag it from there, it works).
It seems that the direct way doesn't work. I understand that the Dropzone Plugin is not designed for that, but it would be a nice feature to put files from other systems directly to the Dropzone element in a APEX application.